# Finding words that are inside successive words

Tags: python, function

```
def sucontain(A):
    C = A.split()
    def magic(x):
        B = [C[i]==C[i+1] for i in range(len(C)-1)]
        return any(B)
    N = [x for x in C if magic(x)]
    return N
Phrase = "So flee fleeting candy can and bandage"
print (sucontain(Phrase))
```

The goal of this function is to create a list of the words that are inside of each successive word. For example the function would take the string ""So flee fleeting candy can and bandage" as input and return ['flee', 'and'] because flee is inside fleeting (the next word) and 'and' is inside 'bandage'. If no cases like these are found, an empty list [] should be returned. My code right now is returning [] instead of ['flee', 'and']. Can  someone point out what I'm doing wrong? thank you

Comment: What does your `magic` function do? I mean, can YOU explain it in your own words?

Comment: the magic function is supposed to check an index of C(a word in the list) and check the successive word (C[i+1] in the range of the length of C(in this case, length of 7, so range(0,7). Then it returns any true case which should then be converted into those words that were true.

Comment: Your magic function tests _equality_, not whether `C[i]` is _in_ `C[i+1]`. That's what you are doing wrong.

Comment: What should happen in case of `"flee fleeting fleetings"`?

Answer (score 7):

Just pair the consecutive words, then it becomes an easy list comprehension…

```
>>> s = "So flee fleeting candy can and bandage"
>>> words = s.split()
>>> [i for i, k in zip(words, words[1:]) if i in k]
['flee', 'and']
```

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely something wrong with your `magic` function.  It accepts `x` as an argument but doesn't use it anywhere.

Here is an alternate version that doesn't use an additional function:

```
def sucontain(A):
    C = A.split()
    return [w for i, w in enumerate(C[:-1]) if w in C[i+1]]
```

The `enumerate()` function allows us to loop over the indices and the values together, which makes it very straight forward to perform the test.  `C[i+1]` is the next value and `w` is the current value so `w in C[i+1]` checks to see if the current value is contained in the next value.  We use `C[:-1]` to make sure that we stop one before the last item, otherwise `C[i+1]` would result in an IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

Looking ahead can be problematic. Instead of testing whether the current word is in the next one, check to see whether the *previous* word is in the current one. This almost always makes things simpler.

Also, use descriptive variable names instead of `C` and `A` and `x` and `B` and `N` and `magic`.

```
def succotash(text):   # okay, so that isn't very descriptive
    lastword = " "     # space won't ever be in a word
    results = []
    for currentword in text.split():
         if lastword in currentword:
             results.append(currentword)
         lastword = currentword
    return results

print succotash("So flee fleeting candy can and bandage")
```